# react-google-recaptcha : Setting window attributes in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, recaptcha

I'm trying to set the recaptcha language dynamically in my application. Looking at the documentation here https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha

> In order to translate the reCaptcha widget, you should create a global
>   variable configuring the desired language. If you don't provide it,
>   reCaptcha will pick up the user's interface language.

```
  window.recaptchaOptions = {
   lang: 'fr'
  }
```

This works if I set the global window.recaptchaOptions object in root app.js file

The issue that I'm trying to resolve is setting the window.recaptchaOptions inside the index.js after creating the store.

Investigating the requests, it looks like the google recaptcha__fr script is pulled in only if I set the global window.recaptchaOptions in the root App. This doesn't allow me to access the store.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this so I can set the window.recaptchaOptions in index.js after creating the store?

Thanks

Comment: Is the reCAPTCHA script pulled in even if you don't render a `ReCAPTCHA` component? If the script isn't loaded until the `ReCAPTCHA` element is mounted, you could render an empty element in place of the `ReCAPTCHA`, then mount it once the language has been defined.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody The script isn't loaded until the ReCAPTCHA is rendered. Can you please elaborate the next sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised an issue here https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha/issues/67

PR will be merged soon.